# How can I get the data in a [[]}?

Tags: javascript, axios

The problem I am getting is I need to get the ID from a API response. The information is in a weird format I have not worked with before so I don't know how I would get the ID data from this response.

(This is my first question so I am sorry if it is not very clear, feel free to leave comments on how I can fix it)

I am interacting with a API and the response data is:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      requestedUsername: 'username',
      hasVerifiedBadge: false,
      id: 7838473284,
      name: 'username',
      displayName: 'username'
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using `.data` but then I would get this result:

```
[
  {
    requestedUsername: 'username',
    hasVerifiedBadge: false,
    name: 'username',
    displayName: 'username'
  }
```

I am trying to get the data for id though and can't find a way to get it

My current code:

```
const userid = await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://users.roblox.com/v1/usernames/users',
  data: {
    "usernames": [
      username
    ],
    "excludeBannedUsers": true
  },
})
console.log(userid.data.id)
```

Comment: data is an array, if only 1 element is present in that array then you have to access it by it's index `console.log(userid.data[0].id)` This means you want to access the id from the 1st element in your data array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data field in the response is an array, and you need to access the first element of this array to get information about the user. Since you want the id field of the user, you can do this:

```js
const response = await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://users.roblox.com/v1/usernames/users',
  data: { "usernames": [username], "excludeBannedUsers": true },
});

const userData = response.data.data[0]; // Access the first element of the 'data' array
const userId = userData.id; // Access the 'id' field of the user object
console.log(userId);
```

In this example, I've separated the steps to make it clearer, but you can also access the id field directly like this:

```js
console.log(response.data.data[0].id);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data` is an array, so it would be:

```js
const response = await axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://users.roblox.com/v1/usernames/users',
  data: {
    "usernames": [
      username
    ],
    "excludeBannedUsers": true
  },
})

console.log(response.data[0].id)
```